# Project Build with Docker Failed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a project locally. I'm not the project owner so I don't know exactly how he set things up. I don't know a lot about docker so I'd be glad if anybody could help.
Here's the issue:
The owner instruct me to run `docker-compose up`.
When I do that I end up getting this error message:

`network api_core_network declared as external, but could not be found`

The file `docker-compose.yml` is configured like this:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  #Nginx Service
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    hostname: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --sort_buffer_size=512K --innodb_sort_buffer_size=512K
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: a
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    # networks:
    #   - api_core_network
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin
      container_name: phpmyadmin
      environment:
       - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      restart: always
      ports:
       - 8080:80
      volumes:
       - /sessions
      networks:
      - api_core_network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  api_core_network:
    external: true
```

This container execute a Mysql database. In this project the `docker-compose.yml` is the only docker configuration file.

Help!

I already look at previous questions here in Stack Overflow and in the Docker Forum but I can't find someone with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;TR: remove `external: true` from the docker-compose.yml.

The following fragment of the docker-compose.yml:

```
networks:
  api_core_network:
    external: true
```

means that the network `api_core_network` is supposed to be already present in docker when starting the project. Hard to say why it was set up that way without knowing the context, most likely the project you are trying to run was a part of a bigger project. If you want to run it in a "stand alone" mode, you can remove `external: true`.